# Find the index of every row of column in another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas noob here.. Couldn't find an answer in SO.  Any help is much appreciated.

I have a DataFrame which has 2 columns. One column is just a Value, and other column is a rolling Min() of the previous 5 values of the first column.

```
+-------+-------+------+ 
| Index | Value | Min5 | 
+-------+-------+------+
|     0 |   1.5 |  1.5 |
|     1 |     1 |    1 |
|     2 |   0.8 |  0.8 |
|     3 |     2 |  0.8 |   --> Ex."0.8" is the min of (1.5, 1, 0.8, 2)
|     4 |   1.3 |  0.8 |
|     5 |   0.9 |  0.8 |
|     6 |     1 |  0.8 |
|     7 |   1.3 |  0.9 |
|     8 |   0.5 |  0.5 |
|     9 |   1.7 |  0.5 |
|    10 |   2.1 |  0.5 |
+-------+-------+------+
```

I would like to make a column that tells me how many rows ago did the current Min value appeared. My goal is to end with a DataFrame like this:

```
+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Index | Value | Min5 | Distance |
+-------+-------+------+----------+
|     0 |   1.5 |  1.5 |        0 |
|     1 |     1 |    1 |        0 |
|     2 |   0.8 |  0.8 |        0 |
|     3 |     2 |  0.8 |        1 |
|     4 |   1.3 |  0.8 |        2 |  --> Ex. 0.8 is 2 rows away (up)
|     5 |   0.9 |  0.8 |        3 |
|     6 |     1 |  0.8 |        4 |
|     7 |   1.3 |  0.9 |        2 |
|     8 |   0.5 |  0.5 |        0 |
|     9 |   1.7 |  0.5 |        1 |
|    10 |   2.1 |  0.5 |        2 |
+-------+-------+------+----------+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) [`np.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html)

```
df.Value.rolling(5, min_periods=1).apply(lambda s: np.argmin(s[::-1]), raw=True).astype(int)

0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     2
5     3
6     4
7     2
8     0
9     1
10    2
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @Tono I'm Glad I could help ! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `idxmin`

```
df.index-df.Value.rolling(5,min_periods=1).apply(pd.Series.idxmin,raw=False)

Out[27]: 
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     1.0
4     2.0
5     3.0
6     4.0
7     2.0
8     0.0
9     1.0
10    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I've been using pandas for a long time and I'm still surprised by things I find ...

Comment: @RockyLi hah me too:-)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what .cumcount() is doing, but it doesn't exactly tells me how far away is the value. Look for example at index 7, the value is 2 places away and in your code (and in my test too), it shows '0' steps away.

Comment: @Tono ok , let me fix it

Comment: @Tono fixed :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found pandas.DataFrame.idxmax works.

```
# create the Value column with index in range(len(Value))
import pandas as pd
Value = [1.5, 1, 0.8, 2, 1.3, 0.9, 1, 1.3, 0.5, 1.7, 2.1]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Value': Value,
})

# Calculate values for the Min5 column
cal_Min5 = lambda x: [min(x[0: i + 1]) if i < 4 else min(x[i - 4: i + 1]) for i in range(len(x))]
df['Min5'] = cal_Min5(Value)

# Calculate values for the Distance column using the idxmax() method
cal_Distance =lambda x: [i - (x == x[i]).idxmax() for i in range(len(x))]
df['Distance'] = cal_Distance(df['Min5'])
print(df)
```

This outputs:

```
    Value  Min5  Distance
0     1.5   1.5         0
1     1.0   1.0         0
2     0.8   0.8         0
3     2.0   0.8         1
4     1.3   0.8         2
5     0.9   0.8         3
6     1.0   0.8         4
7     1.3   0.9         0
8     0.5   0.5         0
9     1.7   0.5         1
10    2.1   0.5         2
```